# HTTP request with custom headers fields using Windows Scripts

Tags: windows, scripting, http-headers

Is it possible to perform a HTTP Request with specific header fields (like 'referer', 'cookies' or 'User-Agent') using Windows Script Host or any other Windows scripting technology??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes (VBScript) :-

```
Dim oWinHTTP


Set oWinHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

oWinHTTP.Open "GET", "http://remoteserver/thing.ext", False
oWinHTTP.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "My Agent String"
oWinHTTP.Send
```

Using WinHttp gives you the greatest level of control, you can use MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0 if you want more effeciently access any XML DOM sent.  Using the standard MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0 component goes throught WinINet at gives you the users proxy settings and cookie store etc, but reduces your control over the conversation.

Answer (score 0):

Can we set the request header like **Cache-control : 'max-age =10000'** using jsp / java?
Actually I want to see the previous page with old data on click of browser's back button only if user comes back to this page with in a specified time , say 10 minutes.

Thanks,
Anurag